# How to send FCM notification to single device from multiple devices

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

If application install in 10 devices then how can FCM notification will send to one of the device.

Comment: Please refer : [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you know how can you send notification from firebase console?

Comment: Use device id, best way to write a cloud function

Comment: check out this -> [Send notification to only one user in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135846/send-notification-to-only-one-user-in-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do that is to send a notification with a topic.

Subscribe the one device to a topic like that: 
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("weather");

More information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging).