# How to send notification to specific user at specific time

Tags: android, laravel, firebase, api, push-notification

I am developing an Android application with backend laravel, how to `push notification` to a specific user with a specific time using `API`?

Also, I found [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and [pusher](https://pusher.com/), so which is better to implement my requirements and how to start?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement your own approach, basically you have to create a db table which keeps subscribe id's or tokens for each user using your application. This tokens can be taken from `Firebase` with like [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceId.html#getInstanceId()). Then, you will be able to send notification via using this tokens from your server.

You can review [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700995/how-to-send-notification-to-specific-users-with-fcm) for more.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this