# How to send data messages to single device using FCM in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm new at using `Firebase cloud messaging` and want to send a message or notification with data to a single device. I've sent notifications to all devices but can't figure out how to send it to a single targeted device. I've looked through many websites and tutorials but no luck.

From one tutorial I was following, I wrote the following code in my

**MainActivity.java :**

```
package in.w3dev.fcm2;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        return;
                    }

                    String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                    String msg = getString(R.string.fcm_token, token);
                    Log.d(TAG, msg);

                }
            });

    }
}
```

But it shows `error : can't resolve symbol getInstanceId(), InstanceResultId`. 
All the things in bold aren't being resolved for some reason. I've already made services extending `FirebaseInstanceIdService` and `FirebaseMessagingService` correctly as described in the FCM window on the right side in the android studio.
Tell me how to resolve these errors or another way to send messages to single devices using FCM.

Also, Is it possible that `InstanceResultId` class can't be imported because of the earlier version of the firebase running in my app?

I tried to upgrade the version but again it showed a bunch of errors so I kept it to `11.0.4` only.

Here is the Gradle file in app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.w3dev.fcm2"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }

    buildTypes {

        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'


}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Use tokens of FirebaseNotifications to send notifi to a specific device.

Comment: How do I do that, can you explain? or provide a link. I'm new at FCM so I need specifics to do it

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37700995/how-to-send-notification-to-specific-users-with-fcm

Comment: @Chandankushwaha yeah I looked at it but don't understand it's answer or approach. For eg. where are these json codes written?

Comment: In Firebase console you can go for Test notification to specific User Device. You have to add token there.

Comment: @Chandankushwaha I just see the compose notification window in the firebase console, can't find test notification :/

Comment: @VarshaVaidywan Go to Cloud Messaging , and then Test Notification

Comment: @Chandankushwaha u mean send test message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send push notification to specific device, your backend server need to store device token and send notification to that token.

You can retrieve current device token and send to server as below.

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }

            // Get new Instance ID token and send to server
            String token = task.getResult().getToken();
            sendTokenToServer(token);
        }
    });
```

And then, you server will you that token to send push notification to that device.

Keep in mind, you cannot use firebase console to send noti directly to specific device as it has no UI contorl for that. But you can use postman to test.

Comment: We can send notification to specific device token from console.

Comment: I've done exactly this @ChanMyaeAung if you'll look at the code in my question..as I said it's showing error:symbol not found. Idk how to resolve this. Also do I need to make separate client and server apps? but how would that work??

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE : I fixed the problem. I updated the android studio to it's newest version and alongside it, the gradle and all other things were updated and with the latest firebase version dependencies added, the code worked just fine.